# Distribute a user input among the predefined numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to build a simple input/output program in java. This program should take an input from a user and then distribute it among the predefined numbers. For example, let's say a user enters 452, and the predefined values are 300, 200, 100, 50. The program should give the output  in a string format as follows: "1x300, 0x200, 1x100, 1x50, with a remainder of 2." However, I can't figure out the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should work:

```
int[] values = {300, 200, 100, 50};
int[] multipliers = new int[values.length];

int input = 452;

for(int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i)
{
    if(input < values[i])
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        multipliers[i] = input / values[i];
        input = input % values[i];
        // It will automatically be an integer because of implict conversion
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < multipliers.length; ++i)
{
    System.out.println(multipliers[i]+"x"+values[i]);
}

System.out.println("Remainder is "+input);
```

## Explanation:

Assuming the values are inputted in descending order, we loop through `values` and set each element of multiplier equal to the number of times `values[i]` can divide the input. Then we set input to the remainder (using the modulo `%` operator) from `values[i]`.

At the end, all the multipliers will be set correctly, and input will be equal to the remainder

Comment: Actually, if condition is useless if you do like `if(input >= values[i])` and `String.format` can be used to store info as string if you don't want to store `multipliers` array and printing using loop again

Comment: How would you do it without loop? String.format only stores info as a string, but we need again to iterate through it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should provide us the code you have tried, to get help.

So I was free to think the solution in my way.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    //should be in descending order
    //key represents predef value
    //value represents the count of predef value
    Map<Integer, Integer> predefinedValues = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    predefinedValues.put(300, 0);
    predefinedValues.put(200, 0);
    predefinedValues.put(100, 0);
    predefinedValues.put(50, 0);

    //get lowestPredef
    int lowestPredef = 50;

    //get input
    int input = 655;

    //iterate until input is higher than lowest
    while(input > lowestPredef){

        //iterate all predefined values
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : predefinedValues.entrySet()){

            int key = entry.getKey();
            int value = entry.getValue();

            //find and stop at first lower value than input
            if(input > key){

                //substract that value from input
                input -= key;

                //count +1 for that value
                predefinedValues.put(key, value + 1);

                //break for-loop
                break;

            }

        }

    }

    //build a string with result
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : predefinedValues.entrySet()){

        result.append(entry.getValue())
                .append("x")
                .append(entry.getKey())
                .append(", ");

    }
    result.append("with a remainder of ")
            .append(input);

    System.out.print(result.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for every number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value = 452;
        Map<Integer, Integer> listofmultiples = new HashMap();
        listofmultiples.put(300, 0);
        listofmultiples.put(200, 0);
        listofmultiples.put(100, 0);
        listofmultiples.put(50, 0);
        int lastKey = 0;
        lastKey = (int) listofmultiples.keySet().toArray()[0];
        int i = listofmultiples.size();
        int valueforkey = 0;
        while (value > lastKey) {
            int key = (int) listofmultiples.keySet().toArray()[i - 1];
            if (value > key) {
                value %= key;
                valueforkey += 1;
                listofmultiples.put(key, valueforkey);
            }
            else{
                i-=1;
                valueforkey=0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(listofmultiples.toString());
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```